# Adding JAR to build path under a folder

Tags: java, eclipse, build, jar

New to Eclipse, and I'm trying to figure out how to add a JAR to a build path UNDER a (what looks like) a library or class path? Here's what I have right now:

[image: http://drivetesting.weebly.com/uploads/1/0/6/3/10633272/8651641_orig.png]

And this is what I want to have:

[image: http://drivetesting.weebly.com/uploads/1/0/6/3/10633272/6219278_orig.jpg]

You see how in the second image, the JARs "core.jar" "ext.jar" and "frameworks.jar" appear under "2231 Libs"? I can't get that to happen, and I've tried everything I can think of. I would really appreciate help with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Java->Build Path->User Libraries preference page. There, define a library and add all your jars to it. Then add the library to your class path in the build dialog box that you show in your screenshot.

[Eclipse Java Help Contents: User Libraries](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/help_preferences_content.htm)